# Analyze Multiple Non-Text Files With Pyspark

Tags: python, multithreading, pyspark

I have several .mat files (matlab) that I want to process with PySpark. But I'm not sure how to do it in parallel. Here's the basic single-threaded setup that I wish to parallelize. The code will generate a list of lists, where each inner list has arbitrary length:

```
filenames = ['1.mat','2.mat',...]
output_lists = [None]*len(filenames) # will be a list of lists

for i,filename in enumerate(filenames):
    output_lists[i] = analyze(filename) # analyze is some function that returns a list
```

Any individual output_lists[i] can fit in memory, but the entire output_lists object cannot. I would like output_lists to be an rdd.

Any ideas? I am also open to using a combination of pyspark and the multiprocessing module. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer looks elegant, but I didn't want to install a new file system. I opted for analyzing the files in parallel with the `joblib` module, writing the results to .txt files, and opening the .txt files with Spark.

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def analyze(filename):
    # write results to text file with name= filename+'.txt'
    return

filenames = ['1.mat', '2.mat', ...]
Parallel(n_jobs=8)(delayed(analyze)(filename) for filename in filenames)
```

Then I use Pyspark to read all the .txt files to one rdd:

```
data = sc.textFile('path/*.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

- Put files in a POSIX compliant file system which can be accessed from every worker (NFS, MapR filesystem, Databricks filesystem, Ceph)
- Convert path so they reflect path in the file system.
- `parallelize`  names:

  ```
  rdd = sc.parallelize(filenames)
  ```
- `map` with `process`:

  ```
  result = rdd.map(analyze)
  ```
- Do whatever you want to do with results.